# Expectation E(Y|X) when P(Y|X) is binomial

Tags: expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X \sim Bin(n, p_1)$, and $Y|X \sim  Bin(m, p_2)$, and I want to calculate E(Y|X).

I can start this off:

$E(Y|X) = \sum_x xP(Y|X)$

$= \sum_x x {x \choose y} p_2^y (1-p_2)^{(x-y)}$

but now what?

Comment: Bayes theorem may be of use: $P(X)P(Y|X)=P(Y)P(X|Y)$

Comment: it is not the same $E(X|Y)$ than $X|Y$? I didn't saw the notation $X|Y$ before. Usually $E(X|Y)$ is the random variable such that $\int_A E(X|Y) dP=\int_A XdP$ for every $A\in \sigma (Y)$

Comment: @Masacroso I've never seen your notation before either! By X|Y, I mean "X given Y" or "X conditional on Y". I've now changed things and hopefully it's clear what I'm looking for, please let me know if additional clarification is needed.

Comment: @StatsSorceress the notation Im talking about is what you see in almost every book of probability theory. It is not clear what means the expression "X given Y", you must have it precise mathematical formulation to make it clear what it is. $Y|X$ seems the same that $E(Y|X)$

Comment: Y|X is the distribution; E(Y|X) is the expected value of Y, given X. This is the standard notation that was used in my undergrad; I expect your notation is more set-theoretic.

Comment: ok, generally it is written as $E(Y|X)\sim \operatorname{Bin}(m,p_2)$, then $E(E(Y|X))=mp_2$. This is why I said it is a bit confusing the notation $Y|X$. In every book of probability theory or statistics the notation $E(Y|X)$ means generally what I said in a previous comment, and sometimes it means what is generally noted as $E(Y|X=x)$, what is something very close but different. In any case $E(Y|X)$ is a random variable, not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y|X \sim  Bin(m, p_2)$, then $E(Y|X)=mp_2$. The fact it is a conditional statement is irrelevant.

Comment: Ugh - I can't believe I didn't see that staring me in the face! Thank you.

Comment: if $E(Y|X)$ is constant then it cannot be the case that it have a binomial distribution. If $E(Y|X)\sim \operatorname{Bin}(m,p_2)$ then $E(E(Y|X))=mp_2$

Comment: @Masacroso: I'm just replying to the question as stated in the opening post. If something is not right, we need the source of the question to confirm it. You're going further than what OP is providing and second-guessing what is wrong. It's likely you're right, but without confirmation of the source material, we don't know.